# Clear controllers on logout

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, controller

I make a logout button in my iOS app, but when you logout and login with a new account, the app stil displays the old data..

Here's my logout hander:

```
@objc func handleLogout(){
        
        do{
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            //UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch let logoutError {
            print(logoutError)
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // UIView usage
            let loginController = LoginController()
            loginController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            
            self.present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
```

How to reset everything when a User logs out ?

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async {` isn't needed here as it's where the main thread exists

Answer (score 0):

You current code will assume logout anyway even if there is an error with `Auth` , so do

```
@objc func handleLogout() {  
      do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()  
            let loginController = LoginController()
            loginController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen 
            self.present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
        } catch {
            print(error)
      } 
}
```

Also you should replace this line

```
self.present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with window's rootViewController change as it will make memory leaks leaving previous vcs  alive  ,  so change it to

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = loginController
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going back to the already existing instance of the `UIViewController` after login. You should be presenting a fresh instance of the previous `UIViewController` once the logout is successful. Try setting the `rootViewController` as `LoginViewController` after logout is successful.

```
@objc func handleLogout(){
    do{
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = LoginController()
        }
    } catch let logoutError {
        print(logoutError)
    }
}
```